# bit manipulation avr assembly

Tags: assembly, avr

I am currently reading a tutorial about avr assembler programming. There is said:

> Bit Manipulation cbr and sbr clear or set one multiple bit(s) in a
>   register. These instructions only work on registers r16 to r31. They
>   do not use single bits as an argument, but masks which can contain
>   multiple bits:

```
sbr r16, (1<<5)+(1<<3) ;set bits 5 and 3 in register 16 
cbr r16,0x03    ;clear bits 1 and 0 in register 16
```

can anybody explain me the parameters of the two instructions?
why do i have to write (1<<5)+(1<<3) in order to set bit 5 and 3? i guess << is something like a bitshifting operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, << is bitshifting.  What you're doing is constructing a bitmask which will be `00101000`, and that will set bits 3 and 5, zero indexed.  In your `cbr` instruction, you're passing the mask 0x03, which is `00000011`, which clears bit 0 and 1.

Comment: so 1<<5 means: 00000001 << 5 = 00100000 and 00000001 << 3 = 00001000. how are these bytes combined? what is the + operator? a logical OR?

Comment: you got it. In your example, they're getting added together, but really a better practice would be to OR them together, like so: (1<<5)|(1<<3). The reason for this is because if you were to do something like this accidentally: (1<<3)+(1<<3), you would get 16, which is 1<<4, and you'd be setting the wrong bit!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier to just write

```
ldi r16, 0x28
```